# clipboard format for xlsx

Tags: format, clipboard, xlsx

I have a table in in html with few columns. I need to make a script to copy lines from that table in clipboard, for pasting later in  excel.
I made script to copy something to clipboard but I dont know how to format/reformat the html text to keep columns when I paste it in Excel.
Hope you understand me!

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure, but I think it is regular `<td>`, if I understood your question correctly of course

Comment: So I need to format clipboarded text from html to paste it in more columns in html:D so if I have this html:
`<table>
    <tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td></tr>
</table>`
I want to keep same format when I paste it to Excel! I tried to paste html as plain text, but...didnt work!

Comment: plain text will only be pasted into a single cell, so you would need to have table format for it to do it correctly

Comment: let me be more clear. When I select entries from a table with mouse, and copy them, then I can paste in Excel keeping initial format(each entry in diferent cell). I want to do that with JavaScript. I tried `$("table tr").html()` but this returns me a html string...and in excel paste only in one cell! I tried `.text()` but not working!

Answer (score 1):

A nice  and simple format for pasting text in Excel is the Tab character ("\t" in Javascript) for cell separator, and new line ("\n" in Javascript) for row separator.